# Grant Elevated Permissions to SQL Server User on Azure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I seem to be getting an error like this when running some SQL against my SQL Server database hosted in Azure..

> The REFERENCES permission was denied on the object 'MyDbTable', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.

Then I try to execute the SQL like this to grant the user elevated permissions:

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'mydbuser'
```

Which fails with:

> Cannot alter the role 'db_owner', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Probably because I'm logged in with the user that doesn't have a high level of permissions and I'm trying to elevate myself..

I don't see an easy way to grant admin level permissions to a SQL Server user in the Azure portal..

Could someone please assist on how to do this in Azure SQL Database?

Comment: What type of Azure product are you using here? Azure Synapse? Azure SQL Database? Azure Managed Instance? Azure *something else*?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to create objects in the `master` database?

Comment: @Larnu valid question another problem that I can address myself later

Comment: @Larnu also I updated the question should be for azure sql database

Comment: Using `master` is part of the problem, so don't address it later, address it now. Move your objects to a user database, configure the permissions there, and then connect to that instead.

Comment: Azure SQL Databases *do* have the `db_owner` role in the `master` database mind, but you *won't* have permissions to alter it (see my prior [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113602/grant-elevated-permissions-to-sql-server-user-on-azure#comment130854768_74113602)). Though you shouldn't be using `sp_addrolemember` anymore either. It's been deprecated since 2012 *at least*.

Comment: @Larnu ok are you saying I should not be encountering this permissions issue if I was not using the master database? I should know how to switch databases.. but if I do and I still encounter this issue then my permissions questions here still remains..

Comment: *"I should not be encountering this permissions issue if I was not using the master database"* **Exactly** this. Even as an adminstrator you *cannot* alter the `db_owner` role in `master` in an Azure SQL Database.

Comment: @Larnu noted let me try that

Answer (score 0):

As @Larnu suggested **you *cannot* alter the `db_owner` role in `master` in an Azure SQL Database.** you are facing this error. I also tried to do like that and got similar error.

[image]

To Overcome this, select particular database and then execute the command

```sql
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'newpratiklg';
GO
```

[image]